# Can Angular Material color intention classes be used with normal HTML elements?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to use Angular Material color intention classes like `md-primary` on normal HTML elements as below:

```
<span class="md-primary">This text is in primary color.</span>
```

But this is not working. I assume that it is because during rendering, Angular applies color intention classes only to the ngMaterial directives.

Am I correct in this explanation? And if so, is there a workaround for this, apart from creating my own CSS classes?

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class color only will work on the Material elements, but there's a work around: 

Just pick the color hex from the Google Material Site http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette


Sample:

`<span style="color: #2196F3"> Material Blue Color</span>`

Answer (score 0):

There are CSS/LESS palettes around, if you don't want to pick all these colors. http://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-color-palette/